# How to fail safe if failure occurs in one of the layer during dockerfile multi-stage builds

Tags: dockerfile

I am writing Dockerfile and using multi-stage build concept to add layers.
One of the FROM layer is docker-sonarqube-scanner that pushes coverage reports to sonar server.
Dockerfile execution fails if this layer fails.
I would want this layer to be fail safe, that said, if there is no coverage report or dir exist, sonarqube should fail silently and Image building process should continue.

````
FROM hub.docker.com/st/docker-sonarqube-scanner:${scannerVersion} as sonar
ARG sonarProjKey
ARG sonarOpts

COPY --from=test /root/app /root/app
WORKDIR /root/app
RUN sonar-scanner --debug -Dsonar.projectKey=${sonarProjKey} ${sonarOpts}```

Where, sonarProjKey is name of project and sonarOpts is sonar options

If above layer fails, image building should continue.
````

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple fix. Use semi-colons as instruction conjunctions and append RUN command with **true**, like this:
`RUN sonar-scanner --debug -Dsonar.projectKey=${sonarProjKey} ${sonarOpts} ; true`